Why Ubuntu 24.04 LTS got stucked in the middle of the installation?
I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS as a Dual boot OS. The middle of the installation shows "How do you want to install Ubuntu?" but there is no disk partition option. I have already created 200 GB of unallocated space. But shows nothing. How can I solve this problem?

are you sure it is unallocated space and not formatted space? :)

Did you made create a 200 gig formatted space?

You can choose "Something Else" and set the 200 GB space as the root partition

@Rinzwind Yes, 200 GB unallocated space.

@Archisman Panigrahi Just showing " How do you want to insatll Ubuntu? ",  nothing else.

Unsure why this is. Could you add an disk layout from command line?

Please post a screenshot of this screen

which part of the "nothing else" you don't understand ....
https://imgur.com/7WIYv1y
I'm pretty sure removing all other drives could help ,but why would i try so hard to remove things from a laptop ...
